# Material UI Modal not working on Highcharts in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, material-ui

I am trying to call a modal when clicking on graph points on Highcharts, I have App.js and Modal.js.
on App.js I use useState to contain the initial value, set it to false, then I passed the value as property to the Modal.js, I tried to console.log inside it and the value becomes set to true.

But I still can't manage to display the modal.

please see the code below

//App.js

```
const App = () =>{

const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)

  function handleOpenModal(){
    setIsModalOpen(true)
  }

  const option10 = {  
    chart:{
      type:'spline'
    },
    title:{
      text: 'Articles Published'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime' //ensures that xAxis is treated as datetime values
    },
    yAxis: {
      title:{
        text: 'Articles'
      }
    },
    plotOptions:{
      series:{
        cursor: 'Pointer',
        point:{
          events:{
            click: function(){
              handleOpenModal()
              //alert("Category: "  + " Articles: " + this.y)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
          return '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' Article' +'</b><br/>'+ 
           Highcharts.dateFormat('%y-%m-%d %l:%M:%P', this.x,true);
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled:false
    },
    series: [{
    
      // number of articles published example
      data: (function(){
          return arr.map(item =>{
            return {x: new Date(item.x).getTime(), y: item.y}
          })
      }()),
      pointInterval: 3600000
    }]
    }

    return(
        <Modal isModalOpen={isModalOpen} />
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={option10} />
    )
```

//Modal.js

```
export default function TransitionsModal({isModalOpen}) {

  //console.log(isModalOpen) the value is set to true when I clicked the points from the graph

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(isModalOpen);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <h2 id="transition-modal-title">Transition modal</h2>
            <p id="transition-modal-description">react-transition-group animates me.</p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wilmer Demata, I have tried to reproduce the issue, but everything seems to work fine. Could you reproduce the problem in codesandbox? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to respond. I am able to fix the issue by adding useEffect on Modal.js